# In SwiftUI how can I add scroll to refresh functionality to List?

Tags: uikit, swiftui

If I have a SwiftUI List that gets its values from my server via API call, such as:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
            ListItemsView(item: item)
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        self.viewModel.getAllItems()
    }       
}
```

The array of items is stored in the @Published var `items`, in viewModel

The func `.getAllItems()` calls a server API which returns an array of items and stores them under the @Published var `items`

How can I add the functionality to swipe down on this `List` and call `.getAllItems()` again, in order to update `items` with new values, and theoretically re-render the `List`?

Or is there a much better way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I'm facing same problem as i understand standard SwiftUI ScrollView cannot do auto scroll. Need to use customized ScrollView

Comment: Did you happen to implement this? Any code would be a great help!

Comment: I was thinking that from api load data portion by portion. let's say first load 10 record then scroll down load more 10 record. But this kind of function i could not find in standard SwiftUI ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 13 and iOS 15+ you can use the new `refreshable()` modifier

```
List(events) { event in
            Text(event.name)
        }
        .refreshable {
            print("Get New Events")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that adds a proper UIRefreshControl to a SwiftUI List's table view: https://github.com/timbersoftware/SwiftUIRefresh

Comment: no it does not add a proper UIRefresh Control